# how to copy cell value into specific location in another cell which already has text

Tags: copy, paste

I want to copy cell value into another cell at specific location which already has some text in it. How to do that??

e.g.

before:

A B
1 the cell already has X as value
2 the cell already has X as value
3 the cell already has X as value
4 the cell already has X as value

After:

A B
1 the cell already has 1 as value
2 the cell already has 2 as value
3 the cell already has 3 as value
4 the cell already has 4 as value

I am pretty new to excel :)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  What does a simple copy/paste produce that you're not getting?

Comment: @marc, the question was how to copy a cell value and paste it in another cell which already has text. e.g. cell1=1234, cell2="Some Text 'X' here" now i want to paste the cell1 value in cell2 at 'X' location. such that cell2 values is finally like cell2="Some Text 1234 here". How do i do that?? Sorry new to stackoverflow so was not able to insert table in e.g. Hope you got the question :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do that.  But you could use the `substitute()` function for the use case you described to combine both strings into a new cell.